# How does upgrade checking work?

Tags: upgrading

I am new to Drupal. I first created my site in Drupal 7, but I had to use Drupal 6 because a lot of the modules I use were not ready yet.  Now I'm noticing more and more modules are having development releases for Drupal 7.

If I install a development release, will the upgrade manager notify me of updates once it's listed as the main module or will I need to switch to the main module to keep getting the notification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you install an official dev version (not a git checkout, but downloaded from the website), it has a date information. If there is a newer stable or dev version, you will be informed.

However, development releases are exactly that. Some work, some work well and others might not work at all.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the Drupal 7 update manager had an issue with development snapshots; when using a development snapshot of a module, the update manager could suggest to install an official release that was released before the last update of the development snapshot; I don't know if this is still true, but I remember I noticed the issue on my test site, months ago.

Comment: I'm having the issue kiamlaluno is talking about. I'm using the -dev verion of views3, updated almost twice a week, and the update manager suggests the official release of weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW [Git deploy](https://www.drupal.org/project/git_deploy) helps here. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Normally drupal.org inserts version information when a project is packaged. Git repositories do not contain this information. Git Deploy hooks into the Drupal update system and attempts to provide the version of modules and themes checked out of git.